# How to properly type the input for String.prototype.replace?

Tags: typescript

I need to keep an array of inputs to [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). When trying to define an interface to use as a type for this array according to the type of the function itself, TypeScript is rejecting with a TS2769 error.

Code:

```ts
interface Replacment {
  searchValue: RegExp;
  replacer: string | ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string);
}

const r1 = {searchValue: /bc/, replacer: 'de'};
const r2 = {searchValue: /bc/, replacer: () => 'de'};
const r3: Replacment = {searchValue: /bc/, replacer: 'de'};
const r4: Replacment = {searchValue: /bc/, replacer: () => 'de'}; // or (_substring: string, ..._args: any[]) => 'de'

'abc'.replace(/bc/, 'de');
'abc'.replace(/bc/, () => 'de');

'abc'.replace(r1.searchValue, r1.replacer);
'abc'.replace(r2.searchValue, r2.replacer);
'abc'.replace(r3.searchValue, r3.replacer); // <-- TS2769
'abc'.replace(r4.searchValue, r4.replacer); // <-- TS2769
```

Error:

```
(property) Replacment.replacer: string | ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string)
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string'.(2769)
```

Any thoughts?

---

`replace` is defined as:

```ts
replace(searchValue: { [Symbol.replace](string: string, replaceValue: string): string; }, replaceValue: string): string;
replace(searchValue: { [Symbol.replace](string: string, replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string; }, replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string;
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this github issue.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `r1` and `r2`, TypeScript infers the types and can definitely say that your `replacer` is either a `string` or a replacement function. So the moment you use it, it knows exactly which function overload of `replace` to use (there are more to it, open `lib.es5.d.ts` to see the other ones.

The moment you annotate, TypeScript is unsure: It can be either `string`, or the replacement function. But which is it? None of the overloads have both types for `replacer`, so TypeScript can't pick the right one.

Disclaimer: TypeScript *could* create the cross-product of all overloads, but as Aplet123 pointed out, that's work in progress: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

What you can do is make it explicit that your `Replacement` type can have either an object with `string` for `replacer`, or an object with function for `replacer`:

```
type Replacment = {
  searchValue: RegExp;
  replacer: ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string);
} | {
  searchValue: RegExp,
  replacer: string
}
```

It's a nuance, but the compiler will narrow down the type to one of those union types at the moment you assign a value. Now you can pass them again.

If you don't have a value assigned, TypeScript still doesn't know what to do with it:

```
declare const r5: Replacment; // no idea what value is assigned, can be both!
'abc'.replace(r5.searchValue, r5.replacer)// <-- TS2769
```

There are two things you can do against that.
A: Narrow in a helper function

```
function replace(str: string, replacement: Replacment) {
   if(typeof replacement.replacer === "string") {
     // I know it's string!
     return str.replace(replacement.searchValue, replacement.replacer)
   }
   return str.replace(replacement.searchValue, replacement.replacer)
}
```

Which is bogus. Or patch String.replace for yourself:

```
interface String {
  replace(searchValue: RegExp, replacer: string | ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string)): any
}
```

Which can be dangerous. Or you do a combination: A helper function that patches String.replace just in the module scope you use it.

Comment: "TypeScript could create the cross-product of all overloads, but deliberately decides against that because this gets too heavy on the compiler too fast." [This is not a deliberate decision, but a design flaw in the process of being fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).

Comment: I don't think modifying a global String interface is a good idea. Just my opinion

Comment: @captain-yossarian I agree! What I do when I need to patch global interfaces is doing that within a module scope, so it's clear what happens where.

Comment: @ddprrt Btw, I have found your blog and book very useful!

Comment: @captain-yossarian Awesome, thank you so much :-) That's so great to get feedback like this!

Answer (score 1):

You should give a tip for TS compiler what do you expect.
For example, you can define generic parameter:

```js
interface Replacment<T> {
    searchValue: RegExp;
    replacer: T extends 'string' ? string : T extends 'fun' ? ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string) : never;
}

const r1 = { searchValue: /bc/, replacer: 'de' };
const r2 = { searchValue: /bc/, replacer: () => 'de' };
const r3: Replacment<'string'> = { searchValue: /bc/, replacer: 'de' };
const r4: Replacment<'fun'> = { searchValue: /bc/, replacer: () => 'de' }; // or (_substring: string, ..._args: any[]) => 'de'

'abc'.replace(/bc/, 'de');
'abc'.replace(/bc/, () => 'de');

'abc'.replace(r1.searchValue, r1.replacer);
'abc'.replace(r2.searchValue, r2.replacer);
'abc'.replace(r3.searchValue, r3.replacer); // no error
'abc'.replace(r4.searchValue, r4.replacer); // no error
```

**UPDATE**

Also, you can achieve same behavior with function overloads:

```js
interface ReplacmentA {
    searchValue: RegExp;
    replacer: string
}

interface ReplacmentB {
    searchValue: RegExp;
    replacer: ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string)
}

type Replacement = ReplacmentA | ReplacmentB

function replacer(arg: ReplacmentA): ReplacmentA['replacer'];
function replacer(arg: ReplacmentB): ReplacmentB['replacer'];
function replacer<T extends Replacement>(arg: T) {
    return arg
}

const r3 = { searchValue: /bc/, replacer: 'de' };
const r4 = { searchValue: /bc/, replacer: () => 'de' };

'abc'.replace(r3.searchValue, replacer(r3)); // no error
'abc'.replace(r4.searchValue, replacer(r4)); // no error
```